# How to create a product registration form in Opencart 2.0

Tags: opencart, registration, opencart2.x

I need the advice of an Opencart whizz please.

I want to create a form where users can register their product guarantees on our website.

We are using Opencart version 2.0 (which I am very new to) and I can't find a way to be able to achieve this from within the interface.

The objective is for us to be able to retrieve and retain the information sent in and notify users of their registration via an email.

I have set up a new page that I want this to sit on but is there a way to create such a form registration form with custom fields?

Comment: It can't really be done through the OpenCart admin so you need to either find an extension or pay a developer from the Commercial Support Forum: https://forum.opencart.com/viewforum.php?f=88

Answer (score 1):

here is a way you can accomplish this. (Although this is not a copy-paste solution, you can use this as your guide):

1. create a controller 
   `catalog/controller/information/form.php`

with two methods: `public function index(){}` for rendering the form and `public function save(){}` for receiving an ajax post to save the form data to the database.

2. create a view file
   `catalog/view/theme/default/template/information/form.tpl` (since you are using v2)

here you should render a form with a onlclick event that should send a `$.post` request to `index.php/route=information/form/save` with the serialized form data

3. add a model file that creates a table in the database where you would store the data and also provides a method for saving the data. `catalog/model/information/form.php`

the model will have two methods: `public function installDatabase(){}` and `public function addData($data){}`

4. and a language file

`catalog/language/english/information/form.php`

Now when you visit the page `index.php?route=information/form` you will see the form and when submited it will be added to the database.

I hope this helps. if you face any issues, leave a comment and I will try to help out;